# How can I convert multiple time-series columns into a cross-sectional data?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, time-series

So I have this dataset:

```
date         col1       col2       col3
20200101     1000       200        300
20200201     4400       500        150
20200301     200        300        400
.
.
.
```

And I want to convert it into this:

```
col1_t0    col1_t1    col1_t2 ... col1_tn    col2_t1    col2_t2 ... col2_tn    col3_t1    col3_t2 ... col3_tn
1000       NaN        NaN     ... NaN        200        NaN     ... NaN        300        NaN     ... NaN
4400       1000       NaN     ... NaN        500        200     ... NaN        150        300     ... NaN
200        4400       1000    ... NaN        300        500     ... NaN        400        150     ... NaN
```

Basically, all t's are lags. It's an adaptation of [What's the most efficient way to convert a time-series data into a cross-sectional one?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64124732/whats-the-most-efficient-way-to-convert-a-time-series-data-into-a-cross-section), same problem, multiple series

Comment: Just make three df and join them together. Change value to col1/col2/col3 in the accepted answer to that question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let us try `shift`

```
df = df.set_index('date')
out = pd.concat([df.shift(x).add_suffix(str(x)) for x in range(3)],axis=1).sort_index(level=0, axis=1)
            col10   col11   col12  col20  col21  col22  col30  col31  col32
date                                                                       
2020-01-01   1000     NaN     NaN    200    NaN    NaN    300    NaN    NaN
2020-02-01   4400  1000.0     NaN    500  200.0    NaN    150  300.0    NaN
2020-03-01    200  4400.0  1000.0    300  500.0  200.0    400  150.0  300.0
```